Как передать в форму параметр 'pk' другой модели
Выбираем категорию вопросов, рандомно берётся вопрос из этой категории, и, отображаются варианты ответов к этому вопросу.
Проблема - не знаю как подать в форму 'pk' выбранного вопроса.
models.py :

from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    possible_ticket_numbers = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def get_questions(self):
        return self.questions.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    number_in_tests = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    right_answer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')

    def get_answers(self):
        return self.answers.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number_in_tests)


class Answer(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content


view.py :

import ast
import random

from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import AnswerForm
from .models import Category, Question


def category_list(request: HttpRequest):
    context = {
        'categories': Category.objects.all()
    }

    for category in context['categories']:
        ticks = [tick.id for tick in Question.objects.filter(category_id=category.pk)]
        category.possible_ticket_numbers = str(ticks)
        category.save()

    return render (request, 'start.html', context=context)


def ticket_request(request: HttpRequest, pk):
    category = Category.objects.select_for_update().get(id=pk)
    # При помощи библиотеки 'ast', получаем список из строки со списком
    list_of_possible_tickets_ids = ast.literal_eval(category.possible_ticket_numbers)

    if not list_of_possible_tickets_ids:
        return render(request, "no_tickets.html", context={"body": "<h1>No Tickets Here !</h1>"})

    # Выбираем случайный билет из предложенного списка, и, удаляем этот билет из списка
    random_ticket_id = random.choice(list_of_possible_tickets_ids)
    list_of_possible_tickets_ids.remove(random_ticket_id)

    # Список - обратно в строку со списком внутри, и - сохраняем в БД
    category.possible_ticket_numbers = str(list_of_possible_tickets_ids)
    category.save()

    ticket = Question.objects.get(category=pk, number_in_tests=random_ticket_id)

    form = AnswerForm()
    return render(request, 'ticket.html', {'ticket': ticket, 'form': form})


forms.py

from django import forms

from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxSelectMultiple

from .models import Answer


class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    question = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Answer.objects.filter(question_id=1),
            label='Выберите ответ :',
            widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['question',]


Здесь в 'queryset=Answer.objects.filter(question_id=1)' , намеренно записал 'id=1' , 

а должно быть 'id=ticket.pk'.
Только как этот 'ticket.pk' сюда передать ?
Буду благодарен за помощь !
На выходе должна быть такая "картинка" :


